# Перемещение кнопки

Tags: html, css

С помощью margin и padding div элемент в виде кнопки перемещается замечательно. 
Как только даю кнопке тип input type = 'button', так она начинает прыгать, и не могу поставить ее в нужное место. 
Как перемещать кнопки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
советую начинать плясать от *{margin:0;padding:0;} и кстати есть еще элемент `<button>`
```

Answer (score 0):

input button отлично поддается стилизации.
padding не задавать
прописать ширину и высоту
дальше как с любым блочным элементом